# Programmatically inserting pictures into cell comments

Tags: excel, vba, comments

I'm trying to create a database in excel that includes images. The best way to do this seems to be to use a comment with the picture as the background of the comment. Unfortunately, I have around 100 observations, and this will be somewhat time consuming.

I'm very new to VBA. I know Python, and Matlab, but I'm just starting VBA.

Essentially, I need to:

1. Create a comment for a given cell
2. Remove any text from the commment
3. Remove any line border from the comment
4. resize the dimensions of the comment to width = 5 inches and height
   = 6.5 inches.
5. fill the background with a specified image.

Now, all the images I need to use are in a specific folder. And I've included the filename in a call adjacent to the cell I'm trying to add the comment to.

So, I'm not exactly sure how to accomplish the above in VBA. I've started by recording a macro that yields some code which I modified to do the exact same thing with multiple cells. The only thing is, I need it to use a *different image* for the background for each comment. How might I accomplish this? It seems like I would need to set up some sort of a loop to go over all of the cells. Then, for the step to change the background, I would need to use the value next cell over to specify the location of the picture I want to use.

Unfortunately, my VBA skills are not quite up to this challenge. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
Sub Macro3()
'
' Macro3 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Option+Cmd+g


'    Range("C25:C50").AddComment
'    Range("C25:C50").Comment.Visible = False
'    Range("C25:C50").Comment.Shape.Select True
'    Range("C25:C50").Comment.Text Text:="" & Chr(13) & ""
'    Selection.ShapeRange.Line.Weight = 0.75
'    Selection.ShapeRange.Line.DashStyle = msoLineSolid
'    Selection.ShapeRange.Line.Style = msoLineSingle
'    Selection.ShapeRange.Line.Transparency = 0#
'    Selection.ShapeRange.Line.Visible = msoFalse
'    Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Visible = msoTrue
'    Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
'    Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.BackColor.RGB = RGB(251, 254, 130)
'    Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Transparency = 0#
'    Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.UserPicture _
'        "OWC Mercury Extreme Pro:Users:austinwismer:Desktop:Flange:IMG_2626.JPG"
'    Selection.ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
'    Selection.ShapeRange.Height = 468#
'    Selection.ShapeRange.Width = 360#
End Sub
```

Comment: For starters [Avoid Select and Activate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select) and take a look at [Range.Offset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840060(v=office.15).aspx). I would imagine you want to create a subrountine that accepts a `Range` and a file path as [parameters](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/byrefbyval.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

The below demonstrates how to do it. Macro Recorder has given you 80% of required methods - all that was needed was some cleaning up (the recorder spits out a lot of junk) and changing some bits to method parameters.

The below shows a dialog to select your images then, starting with the Active Cell, progressively assigns each image to a cell comment as specified in your requirement.

```
'There are lots of ways to get teh filepaths. The below just demonstrate two ways.

Sub Example_UsingSelection()
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Selection
        SetCommentPicture cell.Offset(0, 1), cell.Value
    Next cell
End Sub

Sub Example_UsingFileDialog()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim item

    Set cell = ActiveCell

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        .Title = "Select images"
        .ButtonName = "Select"
        .Show
        For Each item In .SelectedItems
            SetCommentPicture cell, CStr(item)
            Set cell = cell.Offset(1, 0)
        Next item
    End With

End Sub

Sub SetCommentPicture(cell As Range, imagePath As String)

    Dim cm As Comment

    'Get the comment
    If cell.Comment Is Nothing Then
        Set cm = cell.AddComment
    Else
        Set cm = cell.Comment
    End If

    'Clear any text
    cm.Text ""

    'Set comment properties (dimensions & picture)
    With cm.Shape
        .Width = Application.InchesToPoints(5)
        .Height = Application.InchesToPoints(6.5)
        .Line.Visible = msoFalse
        .Fill.UserPicture (imagePath)
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks -- like I said, I'm extremely new to VBA, and I'm trying to learn by doing and copying. I'm wondering how I might do it without inputting the image paths. I actually already have the image paths in the column directly to the left.

Comment: @AustinWismer duly added an alternative example

Comment: @AustinWismer doing and copying with the macro recorder is ok for learning some of the methods of Excel Object Model, but you shoudl ideally learn the basics of the VBA language first so that the output from the MAcro Recorder is intelligible. (I realise a lot of sources just throw you straight in to the deepend using macro recorder - I guess I am old school and think it is useful to learn about things like variable declaration, keywords, expressions etc first).

Comment: Yes -- I am trying to do that right now. I'm going through John Walkenbach's Power Programming with VBA. Unfortunately, the due date for this project is a couple days from now, so for this project, I really don't have time to learn all of the foundations. But I am in the process! Thank you very much for you help!